# how to get SSLContext in wildfly and jakarta-ee

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I created a in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:13.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
<!--   ..... providers, security-domains, ... .....    -->
           <tls>
                <!--   ..........add KS TM and KM -->
                <server-ssl-contexts>
                    <server-ssl-context name="applicationSSC" key-manager="applicationKM"/>
                    <server-ssl-context  name="AuthSSC-V1" protocols="TLSv1.2" key-manager="RVAuthKM" trust-manager="AuthTM"/>
                </server-ssl-contexts>
                <client-ssl-contexts>
                    <client-ssl-context name="AuthSSC-V2" protocols="TLSv1.2" key-manager="AuthKM" trust-manager="AuthTM"/>
                </client-ssl-contexts>
            </tls>
<!--   ..........    -->
</subsystem>
```

and now it tries to get SSLContext

but honestly i dont know how to get it correctly in JAVA

does anyone know how to get this resource in java

tried all day today

```
@Singleton
public class SSLContextAuth {


    @Resource(name = "AuthSSC-V1")
    private SSLContext sslContext;

    public SSLContext getSslContext() throws Exception {
        return sslContext;
    }

}
```

this is what i need to build a rest client

```
        ResteasyClientBuilder builder = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
        builder.establishConnectionTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        builder.socketTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        if(conf.isEnableSSL()) {
            builder.sslContext(sSLContextAuth.getSslContext());
        }
        final ResteasyClient resteasyClient = builder.build();
        final ResteasyWebTarget target1 = resteasyClient.target(REST_URI);
        final AuthApi proxy = target1.proxy(AuthApi.class);
```

Comment: This is not injectable into a bean. What do you need it for?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins i need to build a ResteasyClient

Comment: To my knowledge that is not really possible. You could file a feature request at https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY. However, I don't think injecting the `SSLContext` is correct. What the feature would likely be is a way for inject a `jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client` with the correct SSL context.

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong. I need client REST with TLS -> this tls may change depending on client and security policy
in the standalone.xml file, this seemed to me the most appropriate, because I would have to create SSLContext, but maybe a better solution is to create a REST client in standalone.xml with inject tls

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/Client_Guide.html#authentication-client.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins has  some example how to use this client in java

Comment: I do not currently know of one. It's something that could be considered though.